# are there any backed rules of common placeholder expression

Tags: javascript, java, spring, expression, placeholder

We can see lots of similar placeholder expression in different language, framework. For examples:

**$ and # series:**

```
$param, ${param}, #param, #{param}.
//spring, mybatis use this.
```

**{} series:**

```
{{param}};
//angularjs, vuejs use this;
logger.debug("{}, {}", param0, param1);
logger.debug("{0}, {1}", param0, param1);
//slf4j use this.
```

**% series:**

```
printf("%d, %s", 100, "100");
//C/C++ series language use this.
//log4j use this
```

These expression are similar but a bit different for each different implementation, for example:
C# supports specifying index of arguments: `{0}, {1}`;
but slf4j only supports empty `{}`.

My question is, are there any backed rules for these similar expression implementation that developers follow the rules by default?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: There are no default rules for all languages. Also you can redefine place holders in JS frameworks like Angular. People just choose those characters for placeholder because they are rarely used in normal text.

Comment: I think support for the %-notation is most widespread (Java, C, JavaScript via 3rd party tool, ...). But this is probably mainly due to historical reasons and not for ease of use or feature set. I personally find the %-notation somewhat hard to read, but that's just my personal opinion.